# Print output of a table in R-Viewer

Tags: r, datatable

I want to print out a specific value or cell of a table and want to display it in the viewer. The cell contains a image.  I tried some packages like plot but cant get the image printed out in the viewer. Although i can print it out in the console. I need a package which supports the print out in the viewer. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: do you use R script or Rmarkdown?

Comment: What is the difference? I am using RStudio

Comment: run: `dev.off()` and then plot again.

Comment: This is not working. I edited my coding. Maybe it is helpful

Comment: Could you post `sessionInfo()`

Comment: R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

Comment: You should update R!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to use the "magick" package for this like so:

```
install.packages("magick")
library(magick)

icon_OK <- image_read("PathToSomeImage")
icon_NOK <- image_read("PathToSomeImage")

result1$ICON <- if(result1$TREND>0)icon_OK 
if(result1$TREND<0) icon_NOK
```

To print the image you stored in the ICON column on the first row can be printed in the viewer as follows:

```
print(result1[1,2])
```

If you get an error when loading the package regarding the 'Rcpp' package, then reinstall it as follows:

```
install.packages("Rcpp")
```

It should be noted that you can no longer print/view the dataframe as a whole because there are now pictures in the dataframe. Therefore, you can only inspect individual elements as far as I know.

Comment: I edited my code. Maybe it is helpful

Comment: So it seems you're loading images and store them in the icon_OK and icon_NOK variables right? I think the solution for you is as simple as loading the images using the magick package, and storing them in you're dataframe. Then you can just print the element of interest. I'll edit my answer to make it a bit clearer for your example.

Comment: Yes u got it but I get the following error: Rserve: UnableToOpenBlob `<img src=...'

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this issue? I mean by not importing the package magick

Comment: Not without using another package like for example "imager" I think. How are you currently loading images? I don't think you have to set any <img src=...>, that seems more like html syntax then R. when do you get the error? When running the image_read() function?

Comment: For clarity: if your image is located in "C:/Users/John/icon_OK.jpeg", then you should load this image as such:

icon_OK <- image_read("C:/Users/John/icon_OK.jpeg")

Comment: Ps. I think you might need R version 4.0.5 or higher to use the latest "magick" package version